# Is there any reason to perform a statistical test on a whole population?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, census

Let say I have data of median earnings of an adult in counties of Texas and Arizona and I have data from all such counties. Is there any motivation to run a statistical test on whether these median earnings differ in the two states (let say using a t-test)? Does the result based on a test of "statistical significance" have a meaningful interpretation in this case?

Answer (score 2):

No, this does not make sense.

We run statistical significance testing for population parameters we do not know, so we need to estimate them. We first formulate a null hypothesis (e.g., that the median income in Texas is at least as high as it is in Arizona). We then collect data and calculate a test statistic, ideally one whose distribution under the null hypothesis we know, or can at least approximate. We then compare the observed value of the test statistic with its null distribution. If the observed test statistic would be very unlikely under the null hypothesis, we reject the hypothesis.

However, if we *know* the population parameter, then the entire exercise is completely pointless, because then we *know* whether any null hypothesis is true or not.

Comment: You run a great risk of being misinterpreted.  In this situation, many people *will* perform a test and the result *will* be meaningful because they understand such data are not the "population" in which they are actually interested.  The issue here may lie in the OP misunderstanding the distinction between a sample and a population.